# App crashing when 2nd (or subsequent) call to camera intent is fired on Samsung Galaxy Tab 4 7.0

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-camera-intent

Using Android Studio 1.0, I have an activity with a listview using an adapter to display a custom layout.  The 'setOnItemClickListener' calls a camera intent which works perfectly the first time - 'onActivityResult' retrieves the image, posts it, deletes the file and recycles the memory (memory monitor confirms the GB working correctly here).  The second time it fires, the app crashes after the 'startActivityForResult' call.

The LogCat reports that it cannot find resource id #0x7f030012, which corresponds to my custom layout.  What puzzles me is why the 'doCallbacks' and 'onMeasure' events are being fired when the 'startActivityForResult' method is called the second time.

The app works fine on Titan and Samsung Galaxy S3 devices, but fails on Custom Tablet 4.4.4 API 19 (2560 x 1600) emulator and Galaxy Tab 4 7.0 device.

---

Manifest snippet:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Activity's setOnItemClickListener snippet:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri);
startActivityForResult(intent, CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE);
```

LogCat:

> 12-11 13:10:38.539    4122-4122/com.company.product W/ResourceType﹕
>   Failure getting entry for 0x7f030012 (t=2 e=18) in package 0 (error
>   -75)  12-11 13:10:38.539    4122-4122/com.company.product D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM 12-11 13:10:38.539
>   4122-4122/com.company.product W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: thread exiting
>   with uncaught exception (group=0x41769c08) 12-11 13:10:38.579
>   4122-4122/com.opsi.zeno E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>       Process: com.opsi.zeno, PID: 4122
>       android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f030012
>               at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:2350)
>               at android.content.res.Resources.loadXmlResourceParser(Resources.java:3678)
>               at android.content.res.Resources.getLayout(Resources.java:2166)
>               at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
>               at com.company.product.adapters.WorkflowAdapter.getView(WorkflowAdapter.java:60)
>               at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2738)
>               at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1274)
>               at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1186)
>               at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17478)
>               at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5363)
>               at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1410)
>               at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:695)
>               at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
>               at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17478)
>               at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5363)
>               at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
>               at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17478)
>               at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5363)
>               at com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onMeasure(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:412)
>               at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17478)
>               at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5363)
>               at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
>               at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2548)
>               at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17478)
>               at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2285)
>               at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1396)
>               at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1595)
>               at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1254)
>               at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6624)
>               at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:812)
>               at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:612)
>               at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:582)
>               at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:798)
>               at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
>               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5602)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
>               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283)
>               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099)
>               at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Answer (score 0):

This turned out to be some kind of threading issue.  I added a delay to the 'startActivityForResult()' execution code and the it fixed the problem.  It is more of a hack than a proper solution, perhaps somebody could shed some light on the problem, i.e. why does Android fire the current activity's thread when the new activity is being launched?